# Using SAML to retrieve a list of users from an idp

Tags: onelogin

Given a service like Okta, is it possible to use raw SAML requests to get a list of users from my Okta domain?  We are hoping to use SAML to retrieve users from Okta and generate linked accounts based on those Okta users for them to sign in to our system using SSO, but we need user accounts in our system that are linked to Okta accounts, or any other SSO/SAML/idp provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with SAML. SAML allow user to access other applications from the IDp.

You will need to use their API and authenticate using Oauth, no SAML.
https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html.

Answer (score 1):

What about using Just in time user provisioning based on SAML assertion attributes?

Comment: This should be the approved answer. While not possible to query all users, the common flow is Just In Time provisioning of the user in your system according to the data/claims in the SAML assertions.

Answer (score 0):

SAML is an Authentication/Authorization protocol, not a user management protocol.

If you're using OneLogin, check out their APIs: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/get-users